# If I use up the spaces in the Software Library in the Activity Log, will any other games I play after it is full be recorded?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

In my Activity Log, almost all of the pages in the Software Library are full. Will the pages of the book expand or will any of the games I play after I fill up the Software Library not be recorded?

Comment: Okay... I will try...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Activity Log begins with 16 pages, with eight games each, for a total of 128 records.

When those pages are filled, it will expand to 32 pages, with eight games each, for 256 records.

After *those* pages are filled, it gets more complicated. According to the manual:

> - Records for up to 256 software titles can be stored. If this number is exceeded, records will be deleted, starting with the ones with the shortest play time.
> - However, records for software you have not played in more than 30 days will be deleted before the ones you have played within the last 30 days.

So it will first delete old games, then (if you play more than 256 games in one month!) delete unpopular games.

The games in your daily play log are unaffected.